# How to Extract XML value from Exact Response

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I need to get the value of `Description0, ItemCode` from this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="http://afasfs/services/Exact.Entity.REST.EG/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <id>http://afasfs/services/Exact.Entity.REST.EG/Item/</id>
    <title type="text">Item</title>
    <link rel="self" title="Item" href="Item" />
    <entry>
        <id>http://afasfs/services/Exact.Entity.REST.EG/Item('00X0')</id>
        <link rel="edit" title="Item" href="Item('00X0')" />
        <title />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Description0>HEX S/DRILL SCREW NEO 14-10 X 75 C4 (PK100)</d:Description0>
                <d:ItemCode>0V0X0sdfA</d:ItemCode>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I have tried to do the following but none of them works and having this error

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

```
var itemElements = xDoc.Descendants("feed");
var itemElements = xDoc.Element("feed");
var itemElements = xDoc.Elements("feed");
var itemElements = xDoc.Root.Elements("feed");
var itemElements = xDoc.Elements("feed").Element("entry");

foreach (XElement elem in itemElements.Elements()){}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to include the namespace, e.g `XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"; xDoc.Descendants(atom + "feed");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: Elements not working when I have a namespace in XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993286/linq-elements-not-working-when-i-have-a-namespace-in-xml-file)

Comment: @KlausGütter No

Answer (score 2):

You could use **Namespaces** to get values :

1 - Declare all `Namespace`

```
XNamespace xn = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
```

2 - Query to get `Description0, ItemCode`:

```
var properties = xDoc
    .Descendants(xn + "entry")
    .Descendants(m + "properties")
    .Select(p => new { Description = p.Element(d + "Description0")?.Value, ItemCode = p.Element(d + "ItemCode")?.Value })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

3 - All code :

```
string xml = @"
<feed xml:base=""http://afasfs/services/Exact.Entity.REST.EG/"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"" xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"" xmlns:m=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"">
    <id>http://afasfs/services/Exact.Entity.REST.EG/Item/</id>
    <title type=""text"">Item</title>
    <link rel=""self"" title=""Item"" href=""Item"" />
    <entry>
        <id>http://afasfs/services/Exact.Entity.REST.EG/Item('00X0')</id>
        <link rel=""edit"" title=""Item"" href=""Item('00X0')"" />
        <title />
        <content type=""application/xml"">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Description0>HEX S/DRILL SCREW NEO 14-10 X 75 C4 (PK100)</d:Description0>
                <d:ItemCode>0V0X0sdfA</d:ItemCode>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace xn = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

var properties = xDoc
    .Descendants(xn + "entry")
    .Descendants(m + "properties")
    .Select(p => new { Description = p.Element(d + "Description0")?.Value, ItemCode = p.Element(d + "ItemCode")?.Value })
    .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine($"Description0:{ properties.Description} , ItemCode:{properties.ItemCode}");
```

**Result**

```
Description0:HEX S/DRILL SCREW NEO 14-10 X 75 C4 (PK100) , ItemCode:0V0X0sdfA
```

I hope you find this helpful.